# Unable to deserialize multilayered XML

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

When i am removing the Response Data tag from below XML i am getting proper result.

```
string xmlString = "<BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION><RESPONSE_DATA><RESPONSE_STATUS><CODE>103</CODE>
<MESSAGE>invalid user name/password</MESSAGE></RESPONSE_STATUS></RESPONSE_DATA></BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION>";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

        Console.WriteLine("Records in list: " + productList.Count);
        productList.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.CODE + " - " + item.MESSAGE));
    }
    
    public class Product
    {
        public int CODE{ get; set; }
        public string MESSAGE{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your xml the model will look like below. I have used https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate the model based on the xml

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESPONSE_STATUS")]
public class RESPONSE_STATUS
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE")]
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MESSAGE")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESPONSE_DATA")]
public class RESPONSE_DATA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESPONSE_STATUS")]
    public RESPONSE_STATUS RESPONSE_STATUS { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION")]
public class BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESPONSE_DATA")]
    public RESPONSE_DATA RESPONSE_DATA { get; set; }
}
```

And the serializer should be

```
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION), new XmlRootAttribute("BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION"));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
var bv = (BIOMETRIC_VERIFICATION)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
Console.WriteLine(bv.RESPONSE_DATA.RESPONSE_STATUS.CODE + " - " + bv.RESPONSE_DATA.RESPONSE_STATUS.MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It worked. I am new at this. Thanks for the help.